# How to assign to some of vector elements indexed by a vector?

Tags: matlab

Suppose, I have a vector `v = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]` and I want to assign to `i` and `j` from this vector using an index vector `u = [3, 5]`, so that `i` and `j` take values of `13` and `15` respectively.

I have tried `[i, j] = v(u)` and it did not work. What is the best way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Loosely like the following

```
v = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
u=[3,5];
l = [v(u(1)),v(u(2))];
i = l(1);
j = l(2);
```

or

```
v = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
u=[3,5];

i = v(u(1));
j = v(u(2));
```